# Invalid block tag error. Unable to figure out where have I missed ending block

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I am getting the following error:-

Invalid block tag on line 124: 'endif', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

I am trying to create a pagination system for my listings display. I am trying to figure out where have I missed the ending block.

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        {% if listings.has_other_pages %}
          <ul class="pagination">
            {% if listings.has_previous %}
              <li class="page-item">
                <a href="?page={{listings.previous_page_number}}" class="page-link"
                  >&laquo;</a
                >
              </li>
            {% else %}
              <li class="page-item disabled">
                <a class="page-link">&laquo;</a>
              </li>
            {% endif %}

            {% for i in listings.paginator.page_range %} 
              {% if listings.number == i %}
                <li class="page-item active">
                  <a class="page-link">{{i}}</a>
                </li>
              {% else %}
                <li class="page-item">
                  <a href="?page={{i}}" class="page-link">{{i}}</a>
                </li>
              {% endif %} 
            {% endfor %}
        
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    </div>
```

I have added the above code to the code below. If I remove this then the codes work perfectly.
The whole code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% load humanize %} {% block content %}

<section id="showcase-inner" class="py-5 text-white">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1 class="display-4">Browse Our Properties</h1>
        <p class="lead">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt,
          pariatur!
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- Breadcrumb -->
<section id="bc" class="mt-3">
  <div class="container">
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item">
          <a href="{% url 'index' %}"> <i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Browse Listings</li>
      </ol>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- Listings -->
<section id="listings" class="py-4">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      {% if listings %} {% for listing in listings %}
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card listing-preview">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ listing.photo_main.url }}" alt="" />
          <div class="card-img-overlay">
            <h2>
              <span class="badge badge-secondary text-white"
                >${{listing.price | intcomma}}</span
              >
            </h2>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="listing-heading text-center">
              <h4 class="text-primary">{{ listing.title }}</h4>
              <p>
                <i class="fas fa-map-marker text-secondary"></i>
                {{ listing.city }} {{ listing.state }} {{ listing.zipcode }}
              </p>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div class="row py-2 text-secondary">
              <div class="col-6">
                <i class="fas fa-th-large"></i> Sqft: {{ listing.sqft }}
              </div>
              <div class="col-6">
                <i class="fas fa-car"></i> Garage: {{ listing.garage }}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row py-2 text-secondary">
              <div class="col-6">
                <i class="fas fa-bed"></i> Bedrooms: {{ listing.bedroom }}
              </div>
              <div class="col-6">
                <i class="fas fa-bath"></i> Bathrooms: {{ listing.bathrooms }}
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div class="row py-2 text-secondary">
              <div class="col-12">
                <i class="fas fa-user"></i> {{ listing.realtor }}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-secondary pb-2">
              <div class="col-6">
                <i class="fas fa-clock"></i> {{ listing.list_date | timesince }}
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <a
              href="{% url 'listing' listing.id %}"
              class="btn btn-primary btn-block"
              >More Info</a
            >
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      {% endfor %} {% else %}
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <p>No Listings Available</p>
      </div>
      {% endif %}
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        {% if listings.has_other_pages %}
        <ul class="pagination">
          {% if listings.has_previous %}
          <li class="page-item">
            <a href="?page={{listings.previous_page_number}}" class="page-link"
              >&laquo;</a
            >
          </li>
          {% else %}
          <li class="page-item disabled">
            <a class="page-link">&laquo;</a>
          </li>
          {% endif %} {% for i in listings.paginator.page_range %} {% if
          listings.number == i %}
          <li class="page-item active">
            <a class="page-link">{{i}}</a>
          </li>
          {% else %}
          <li class="page-item">
            <a href="?page={{i}}" class="page-link">{{i}}</a>
          </li>
          {% endif %} {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: please show the whole code, I mean all of the html

Comment: maybe because you mixed different tags in same line. example `{% if listings %} {% for listing in listings %}`, `{% endfor %} {% else %}`, `{% extends 'base.html' %} {% load humanize %} {% block content %}`